# Erase item from vector passed to new thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

I have a program that saves in a vector a reference and the thread id of the newly created thread.

```
void remote_forwading_thread(std::vector<std::pair<std::thread::id, std::thread>>& thread_vector) {
  [...]
   for (const auto& th : thread_vector) {
        if (th.first == std::this_thread::get_id()) {
            thread_vector.erase(th); <--- ERROR
            break;          
        }
    }
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::thread::id, std::thread>> thread_vector;
[...]
std::thread t(remote_forwading_thread, &thread_vector);
thread_vector.emplace_back(std::make_pair(t.get_id(), std::move(t)));
```

The errors I'm getting are:

> 1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(214,79): error
>   C2100:  illegal indirection
>   1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(220,35): error
>   C2664: 
>   'std::_Vector_iterator>>
>   std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator>>,std::_Vector_const_iterator>>)':
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'const
>   std::pair' to
>   'std::_Vector_const_iterator>>'
>   1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(220,35): error
>   C2664:         with
>   1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(220,35): error
>   C2664:         [
>   1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(220,35): error
>   C2664:             _Ty=std::pair
>   1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(220,35): error
>   C2664:         ]
>   1>C:\Users\user\Documents\code\project\src\client.cpp(220,33): message
>   :  No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I count at least four fundamental problems with the shown code. There are too many problems here to fully explain. Even if you manage to get the code to compile, as shown this is a pile of race conditions and undefined behavior, and I expect the shown program to be randomly crashing, all the time.

Answer (score 4):

1. You may not perform operations that invalidate the iterators when looping with a range-for loop. `std::vector::erase` invalidates the input iterator. If the program compiled, then it would have undefined behaviour.
2. The element type of a vector can not be an iterator to that vector. Since the argument of `std::vector::erase` is an iterator to the vector, passing an element of the vector - which appears to be a pair - to it is ill-formed. This is what the compilation error tells you.

You should simply use the erase-remove idiom to fix 1 and 2.

3. There appears to not be any synchronisation between modifying the same vector both in main thread, as well as in the new thread, so there is a data race. The behaviour would be UB, if the program compiled in the first place. You probably need to use a lock and possibly a condition variable.
4. Argument type of `remote_forwading_thread` is a reference to a vector, but you are passing a pointer to vector. These types don't match, so the program is ill-formed. You should use `std::ref` in this case.
5. Erasure of the thread object from the vector causes the thread wrapper to be destroyed, which has undefined behaviour since the thread has neither been detached, nor joined. If you detach, then storing the empty thread wrapper in the vector seems pointless. If you erase after join, that cannot possibly happen within the thread, since it has to end before it joins. So, there is simply no way for this to work. You really need to re-think what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: You've got three out of four problems here. There is one remaining, obvious problem with the shown code that will result in another compilation error, after getting past this one (and the compilation error is actually a two-parter).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I found one more. Is this the same you were thinking of?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik found fifth one.

Comment: Yup, that was rather obvious.